# C# FlowLayoutPanel MouseMove event not detected on scrollbar

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, scrollbar

I have a FlowLayoutPanel with AutoScroll = true
I need to detect the movement of the mouse on the scrollbar when the scrollbar is visible.

The MouseMove event of the FlowLayoutPanel does not capture events pertaining to the scrollbar.

Is there any way to hook on to the mouse move of the scrollbar?

Comment: Can you explain a bit why you need to react on mouse-move over the scroll bar?

Comment: well what ever he is trying to do..i just realized that scrollbar neither comes in forms area nor FormLayoutPanel's area..or mousemove event is not raised on when on it..Hmmmm. let me see what we can do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class MyFlowLayoutPanel : FlowLayoutPanel
{
    const int WM_NCMOUSEMOVE = 0x00A0;

    protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
    {
        if( m.Msg == WM_NCMOUSEMOVE )
        {
            Console.WriteLine("MouseOverScrollbar");
        }

        base.WndProc(ref m);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried this(in LINQPAD) and looks like when mouse is on scrollbar MouseMoveEvent is not raised.

```
void Main()
{
    Application.Run(new Form2());
}

public class Form2:Form
{
public Form2()
    {
        Label lbl= new Label();
        lbl.Location = new Point(200,40);
        this.Controls.Add(lbl);
        FlowLayoutPanel fl = new FlowLayoutPanel();fl.AutoScroll =true;
        fl.MouseMove += (s,e) => { lbl.Text = e.Location.Y.ToString();};
        this.MouseMove += (s,e) => { lbl.Text = e.Location.Y.ToString();};
        for(int i=0;i<10;i++){fl.Controls.Add(new Button());}
        this.Controls.Add(fl);

    }
}
```

[image]

These's [ScrollBar.MouseMove](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.scrollbar.mousemove%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) event but its not available for direct use by us.

*Wait while i see if there is any wokaround*